# Magnetometer- there is no low current feature?

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism

I have gone over all magnetometers available, most of them using I2C, and connected to some MCU, and i couldn't find even one with interrupt.

That means the processor cant go to sleep, and always has to listen to what is going on, there is no interrupt on change option in any of them.

Is there something special about them that none of them have an interrupt when a threshold is met?

```
LSM303
MAG3110
HMC5883L
```

How can you build battery operated devices that sense motion when you always have to listen?

Accelerometers (that can't detect slow movement) always have some interrupt, but magnetometers do not .

Any help/replacement about this issue would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of threshold would you expect from a magnetometer?

Comment: Anyway, a simple "magnetometer interrupt" search on google giving [this](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM89/SC1449/PF255198) as a first result.

Comment: for example a change above some constant number that produce interrupt . (a movement? )

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you will read about this one a little bit more, you will find that interrupt are only "inertial" and not for the magnetometer.

Comment: Inertial what??? It is a magnetometer, no inertial sensor inside. "The device may be configured to generate
interrupt signals for magnetic field detection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Accelerometers( that cant detect slowly movement) are always has some interrupt, but magnetometers are not .

You can try to detect slow movements (turns) by sampling the magnetometer at a low frequency (e.g. once per second or per minute). This should not consume much energy even for a battery operated device.

Comment: and whats the point of that? you want to know when something was moved at the moment it happens..

Comment: "turns" are best detected by gyros. Why not to use a proper sensor for the application?

Comment: what you mean by turns? a door open? a window slide to the left?

Comment: The noise on a gyro usually won't let you detect *slow* turns.

Comment: For window open sensing with interrupt the traditional solution is a reed switch..

Answer (score 1):

The ST LSM9DS1 seems to offer interrupts for its magnetometer (positive and negative thresholds for every axis) according to its datasheet on page 67/72.